# Conditional expectation of two random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Let A$_1, A_2$ be two i.i.d random variables such that $0< A_1 <1$ and $0< A_2 <1$. Let $A_m$ be a constant such that $0< A_m <1$.

Can we say that $\mathbb{E}[A_1 | A_1 < A_m, A_2 < A_m] = \mathbb{E}[A_1 | A_1 < A_m] $?

Answer (score 2):

$E[A_1 | A_1 < A_m, A_2 < A_m] = E[A_1 | A_1 < A_m] $

Yes. Since $A_1$ and $A_2$ are independent r.v.s, the events $[A_1 < A_m]$ and $[A_2 < A_m]$  are independent.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent ,then $E[X|Y] =E[X]$. We can easily prove this by replacing f(x|y)= f(x) integral or summation expression of expectation.

Comment: The fact that these two events are independent is not enough.

Comment: What other conditions do we need ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $B_i=[A_i\lt A_m]$. By definition, $E[A_1\mid B_1,B_2]=E[A_1\mathbf 1_{B_1}\mathbf 1_{B_2}]/P[B_1\cap B_2]$. Since $A_1\mathbf 1_{B_1}$ is a function of $A_1$, $\mathbf 1_{B_2}$ is a function of $A_2$ and $(A_1,A_2)$ is independent, $(A_1\mathbf 1_{B_1},\mathbf 1_{B_2})$ is independent hence $E[A_1\mathbf 1_{B_1}\mathbf 1_{B_2}]=E[A_1\mathbf 1_{B_1}]\,E[\mathbf 1_{B_2}]=E[A_1\mathbf 1_{B_1}]\,P[B_2]$. Likewise, $P[B_1\cap B_2]=P[B_1]P[B_2]$.

Hence $E[A_1\mid B_1,B_2]=E[A_1\mathbf 1_{B_1}]/P[B_1]=E[A_1\mid B_1]$, QED.